# Use Jmeter localhost with custom port

Tags: java, apache, testing, localhost, jmeter

I have a Java web-server. It uses localhost, and port 9090.(custom, but not 8080)

```
(Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=59507,localport=9090]) // in the log
```

It works fine, and I wont to test it using Apache JMeter.

Here is my structure
(The HTTP requests match its Names.)
[image]

When I start it - the log shows following errors:

```
<httpSample t="157" lt="0" ts="1356605101476" s="false" lb="/index.html" rc="Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" rm="Non HTTP response message: null" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2021"/>
<httpSample t="10" lt="0" ts="1356605101637" s="false" lb="/about.html" rc="Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" rm="Non HTTP response message: null" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2021"/>
<httpSample t="16" lt="0" ts="1356605101651" s="false" lb="/404e.html" rc="Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException" rm="Non HTTP response message: null" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text" by="2021"/>
```

I will be very appreciative if you give me some hints.

Comment: It's easier to debug using View Results Tree

Comment: @AndreyBotalov, Thank for your advice, but I have got the same results in my log file.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that localhost:9090 works fine in browser with the URLs you use.
Then try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thank yur for your reply. Yes, I tried. The browser shows the page correctly, as well as I used "localhost:9090". But JMeter shows the same errors(